# Call a function with different parameters and wait till the first execution has finished

Tags: javascript, react-native, vue.js, push-notification

I have a react native project which prints some data received through notifications. To print I am using the Sunmi Inner Printer V2. The problem I am facing is with the printing not following the format I want it to. The font size, alignments and placement of data is being mixed up when I am receiving two or more notifications at the same time. I am assuming that this is because the print function is being called before the previous print call is complete. I tried using async/await but it didn't solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [async.queue](https://github.com/async-js/async#async.queue) with a concurrency of 1.